# Refund policy for a risk-free purchase of a short online course

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, e-learning

I am building a website for celling and teaching online courses of my own making. Consider a course that consists of 50 videos for a total of seven hours. I would like to offer a refund policy that will alleviate the potential student's doubts regarding the possibility of a poor quality course. On the other hand, I would like to protect myself from people learning the whole course and requesting a full refund (though I wonder how many people would go for this if they really got value from the course).

I am thinking of offering a refund policy, whereby one can only obtain a refund within one week of the purchase and only if they have watched through less than 70% of the videos. Would such a refund policy make for a risk-free purchase?

Comment: This question fits better in [Economics SE](https://economics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Danielillo I did not find any tags fitting this question at that forum... I posted it with the best tag I could find and will see what happens... Thank you for the suggestion. https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/48084/refund-policy-for-a-risk-free-purchase-of-a-short-online-course

Comment: I think you will have a better chance of finding an answer than here. It's a relatively new forum (12,000 questions). Good luck!

Comment: @Danielillo They told me in the comments there that I could not find tags because the question was not in the field of economics...

Answer (score 1):

This is highly subjective.
Just like with pricing models, i would recommend you to make a survey on students.

Offer them a few refund policy models and ask them what they would consider "fair".

Comment: Great idea, though I cannot imagine how students would not lean towards a very low price...